# NancyFx form auth. without Asp.Net

Tags: asp.net, wcf, nancy

Is it possible to use NancyFx form authorization without Asp.net (or IIS)? I want to use wcf hosting, so I would like to know whether it is possible?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course - nothing in Nancy is tied to Asp.net or IIS, apart from the obviously named ASPNet packages for hosting - you can use the Forms auth with any hosting option.